# Having problems with php pdo query while loop

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a db table that has two columns, id and category. my aim is to use a while loop to echo out the category from the db into a li and an anchor.

Here's the code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <?php $connect = new db();
                          $stmt = $connect->link->query("SELECT * FROM categories")->fetchall();
                          while($row = $stmt){
                            $category = $row["category"];
                            echo "<li><a href='#'>{$category}</a></li>";
                          }

                    ?>
                </ul>
```

i am getting an error but it doesnt make sense to me. its saying undefined index "category". its referring to where i assigned $category to the $row[].

i know for sure that the data is being pulled because i used the print_r() function and it printed them out

edit: as requested the output from a var_dump()

```
C:\wamp64\www\cms\CMS_TEMPLATE\includes\nav.php:21:
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'category_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      'category' => string 'bootstrap' (length=9)
      1 => string 'bootstrap' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'category_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      'category' => string 'javascript' (length=10)
      1 => string 'javascript' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'category_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      'category' => string 'html' (length=4)
      1 => string 'html' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'category_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      0 => string '4' (length=1)
      'category' => string 'css' (length=3)
      1 => string 'css' (length=3)
```

Comment: Show the output of `var_dump($row)`

Comment: Try $row->category

Comment: Barmar i edited the original post to show the var dump. bassem samir, thanks but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

`$stmt` is a list of all of the rows in the database - you use `->fetchall();` to get the results of the query - this means it is a 2 dimensional array with rows indexed by numerics and each row having the field names.  So you would be better of replacing

```
while($row = $stmt){
```

with something that would loop over the results...

```
foreach ( $stmt as $row ) {
```

If you need to use a while loop, then you can remove the `fetchAll` and use the while loop to fetch each row one at a time with `fetch()`...

```
$stmt = $connect->link->query("SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
```

Comment: i wanted to avoid using a foreach loop as it apparently takes up more space in memory. plus i need the practice with while loops and pdo. does anyone have a solution regarding the while loop?

Comment: I've updated with a while loop, but the issue with `foreach()` taking more memory is not worth worrying about.

Comment: Thanks @nigel Ren. it was driving me nuts